# Powershell Studio Get-ChildItem -Path -filter and do action

Tags: powershell, contains, get-childitem

I have created a PowerShell studio app a gui tool for PowerShell syntax still applies really. I need to search a folder for a file filter  "*DeploymentConfig_custom*" which works fine. I now need to set if statement and set a checkbox to $true if it finds that file in the folder.

My attempt

```
    $deploymentcheck.Checked = $false

[string]$deployment = Get-ChildItem -Path $Pkgpathmain.Text -Filter "*DeploymentConfig_custom*"


if ($deployment -contains "*DeploymentConfig_custom*")
{
    $deploymentcheck.Checked = $true    
}
```

Comment: -Contains applies to arrays and you converted the result to string. Will test but does match work in this case `$deployment -match "DeploymentConfig_custom"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[string]$deployment = Get-ChildItem -Path $Pkgpathmain.Text -Filter "*DeploymentConfig_custom*"
```

That code would return a string with all the file names delimeted with a space. You are using `-Contains`  against that string. `-Contains` looks for array elements and would always fail in this case since `$deployment` is a single string and not an array. You should try to use `-match` or `-like`

```
if ($deployment -like "*DeploymentConfig_custom*")
```

of

```
if ($deployment -match "DeploymentConfig_custom")
```

`-Match` support regular expressions so you would not need to use any `*`'s in your case.

That should work in your PowerShell studio app